# Facebook Site Url

Tags: facebook

I want my facebook app to have the site URL to be http://ronzohan.comze.com/redirect.php.
But facebook tells me that it is not a valid URL. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site url needs to lead to a domain or path on that domain, not a particular file. So http://ronzohan.comze.com/ would work, but http://ronzohan.comze.com/file.php would not.

Keep in mind you can pass a `redirect_uri` in the authentication process to send them to http://ronzohan.comze.com/redirect.php once the user has authorized the app.